# how to integrate twitter followers in iphone with all detail?

Tags: iphone, twitter, mgtwitterengine

i have integrated twitter in my iphone App successfully  and posted twits but in addition i need followers list with detail so how can i get my following and followers detail specially email id.
there is any API available or not for Followers and Following i search but i m getting no idea ..Please let me know if any one have any idea.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People following **you**(user)

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

example call : [https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&**screen_name=twitterapi**](https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi)

People **you**(user) are following

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids

example call:  [https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&**screen_name=twitterapi**](https://api.twitter.com/1/friends/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi)

. . . but you won't be able to get their email I.D's. This is private and privlaged information unavailable to to developers using the Twitter API.

Comment: Thanx alot liya for taking your valuable time for me